# DbContext not update when multiple requests are sent in a short time

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, inversion-of-control, autofac, object-lifetime

Currently I'm developing a web system for my company using angularjs and web api 2.

In the system, we allow users to add account into database by using an api.
This is its flow:

- Call api/user to add user into database.
- Add user information with specific information:

  - Id (auto generated by DB)
  - RepresentationCode (calculated by concatenating USER_REPRESENTATION_{MaxUserIndex}

Let me give you an example, let say the database is empty.

- Call api/user 20 times concurrently.
- These are the records that are created into database.

**1 USER_REPRESENTATION_1   2018-03-17 01:51:02.140 NULL**

**2 USER_REPRESENTATION_1   2018-03-17 01:51:02.140 NULL**

**3 USER_REPRESENTATION_3   2018-03-17 01:51:02.417 NULL**

**4 USER_REPRESENTATION_3   2018-03-17 01:51:02.420 NULL**

5   USER_REPRESENTATION_4   2018-03-17 01:51:02.427 NULL

**6 USER_REPRESENTATION_6   2018-03-17 01:51:02.437 NULL**

**7 USER_REPRESENTATION_6   2018-03-17 01:51:02.437 NULL**

8   USER_REPRESENTATION_8   2018-03-17 01:51:02.443 NULL

User representation codes are duplicated with some records.

- My expectation is:

1   USER_REPRESENTATION_1   2018-03-17 01:51:02.140 NULL

2   USER_REPRESENTATION_2   2018-03-17 01:51:02.140 NULL

3   USER_REPRESENTATION_3   2018-03-17 01:51:02.417 NULL

4   USER_REPRESENTATION_4   2018-03-17 01:51:02.420 NULL

5   USER_REPRESENTATION_5   2018-03-17 01:51:02.427 NULL

6   USER_REPRESENTATION_6   2018-03-17 01:51:02.437 NULL

7   USER_REPRESENTATION_7   2018-03-17 01:51:02.437 NULL

8   USER_REPRESENTATION_8   2018-03-17 01:51:02.443 NULL

This is the code for registering DI :

```
        // Initiate container builder to register dependency injection.
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

        #region Controllers & hubs

        // Controllers & hubs
        containerBuilder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
        containerBuilder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(httpConfiguration);

        #endregion

        #region Unit of work & Database context

        // Database context initialization.
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<RelationalDbContext>().As<DbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        // Unit of work registration.
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        #endregion

        #region IoC build

        // Container build.
        containerBuilder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(httpConfiguration);
        var container = containerBuilder.Build();

        // Attach DI resolver.
        httpConfiguration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

This is my `ApiUserController`

```
    public IHttpActionResult AddUser()
    {
        // Get users list.
        var users = _unitOfWork.Users.Get();

        // Get max user id.
        var iMaxUserIndex = users.Max(x => (int?)x.Id) ?? 0;
        iMaxUserIndex++;

        var user = new User();
        user.RepresentationCode = $"USER_REPRESENTATION_{iMaxUserIndex}";
        user.CreatedTime = DateTime.Now;

        _unitOfWork.Users.Add(user);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();

        return Ok();
    }
```

After searching for solution, this is the temporary solution I'm using. I use trigger to update user representation code when record is created.

Below is my trigger:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [type] = 'TR' AND [name] = 'addUserRepresentationCode')
DROP TRIGGER addUserRepresentationCode
GO
CREATE TRIGGER addUserRepresentationCode ON [dbo].[Users] 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @userId  INT;
 SELECT @userId = Id FROM INSERTED
 UPDATE [dbo].[Users] 
 SET  RepresentationCode = 'USER_REPRESENTATION_' + CAST(@userId as varchar(10))
    WHERE Id = @userId
END
```

My trigger works fine, meet my requirement.

But I still have one question:

- Can I add user representation code with pure Entity Framework without any helps from trigger ?

Thank you,

Comment: You should use a computed column for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because multiple consecutive requests may end up getting the same `iMaxUserIndex` value.

For example, request A hits your controller and executes this line:

```
var iMaxUserIndex = users.Max(x => (int?)x.Id) ?? 0;
```

Then, request B hits your controller and executes the same line above before the thread for request A could add the entity and save the database. The result is that both requests have the same `iMaxUserIndex` value.

The easiest options to set `RepresentationCode` variable is either make it a computed column in your database, or if you don't need that column in the database, just make it a read only property in your domain model.

```
public string RepresentationCode { get; } = $"USER_REPRESENTATION_{Id}";
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I've follow this question about computed column. For now, it works fine :)